# Can we use Flash Player to play video stream from other media server(rather than FMS)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I am curious, is it possible to play video stream from non-adobe(or homebrew server), in the newest flash player(10).

It looks like the VideoPlayer only plays the stream from FMS? Is it the business model of Adobe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One friend suggests me to use http server! It's a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) instead of FMS.

Comment: Is it possible to use RTP with Flash Player or P2P technology?